# Using querydsl with undetermined schema with mongo and spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, querydsl

I've the following mapping:

```
@Document
class Event {
   Object carbonCopy; 
}
```

`carbonCopy` has several attributes and its schema is undetermined - various events can have different set of attributes. Assume that `carbonCopy` has `status` field. I need to find all `Event`s that have `carbonCopy.status` equal to `NEW`. Is it possible with query DSL, how? I'm struggling with various mixes of `Path` and `Expression` instances to no avail.

Comment: Can you please look into below link may it help you. 

http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02s07.html

Comment: @RaheelaAslam have you checked the link before suggesting it? Is there any particular section I should pay attention to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible with the following piece of code:

```
QEvent event = QEvent.event;

PathBuilder<Event> query = new PathBuilder<Event>(Event.class, "entity");
BooleanExpression expr = query.getMap("objectCarbonCopy", String.class, String.class).get("status").eq(Expressions.constant("NEW"));
```

Where `QEvent` is querydsl generated class.

Answer (score 2):

You can use similar like 
in terminal
 `db.events.find({"carbonCopy.status":"NEW"})`
in termilnal if you need existance as well

```
db.events.find({carbonCopy.status:{"$exists":true}},"carbonCopy.status":"NEW"})
```

NOW when it comes to SDM

`Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("carbonCopy.status").is("NEW")`

`Query query = new Query(criteria);`

`return  mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Event.class);`

`Criteria criteria =    Criteria.where("carbonCopy.status").is("NEW").And("carbonCopy.status").exists(true)
 Query query = new Query(criteria);
return  mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Event.class);`